# angular Auto-complete formInit doesnt fill my value

Tags: angular, autocomplete

i have this auto-complete inside form

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Pilih Bank" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName="bankName">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)='onChangeBank()' [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <mat-option>Pilih Bank</mat-option>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
    {{option.bankName}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

when i try to `initForm()` and user have the value for bankName, i want to fill the `formControlName` with the user value, but it wont change anyway.

this is inside my `TS

```
// Angular
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output, ViewChild, OnDestroy }          from '@angular/core';
import { ViewportScroller }                                            from '@angular/common';
import { AbstractControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, NgForm, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute }                                              from '@angular/router';
// Extension
import { Subject, Subscription, Observable }                         from 'rxjs';
import {map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { distinctUntilChanged, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as _                              from 'lodash';

import { ValidationsService } from '../../../shared/validations.service';
import { BankService }        from '../../../shared/bank.service';

export interface User {
  bankCode: string;
  bankName: string;
}

@Component({
  selector   : 'fp-kyc-legal-data-form',
  templateUrl: './fp-legal-data-form.view.html',
  styleUrls  : ['../fp-kyc.style.scss']
})
export class FpLegalDataFormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  form: FormGroup;
  tmpIdentityImg: string;
  tmpPaySlipImg: string;
  tmpTaxImg: string;
  tmpDocument: string;
  isSubmitted: boolean;
  kliringCode= new Subject<string>();
  getBankAccountSub : Subscription;
  kliringCodeSub : Subscription;
  convertBankCodeSub : Subscription;
  interval;
  timeLeft: number;
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: User[];
  filteredOptions: Observable<User[]>;

  public profileData;
  private limitSizeUpload = 5242880;

  private unSubs$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  @Output('legalDataStatus') legalDataStatus: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @ViewChild('legalDataFrm') legalDataFrm: NgForm;

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public _validationsService: ValidationsService,
    private $viewportScroller: ViewportScroller,
    public _bankService: BankService
  ) {
    this.$viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
    this.profileData    = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data.profile;
    this.tmpIdentityImg = '';
    this.tmpPaySlipImg  = '';
    this.tmpTaxImg      = '';
    this.tmpDocument    = '';
    this.isSubmitted    = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
    this.initDropdown();
    this.form.statusChanges
        .pipe(
          takeUntil(this.unSubs$),
          distinctUntilChanged()
        )
        .subscribe((status: string) => {
          this.legalDataStatus.emit(status === 'INVALID');
        });
  }

  displayFn(user?: User): string | undefined {
    console.log(user)
    return user ? user.bankName : '';
  }

  private _filter(name: string): User[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.bankName.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.kliringCodeSub) this.kliringCodeSub.unsubscribe();
    if(this.getBankAccountSub) this.getBankAccountSub.unsubscribe();
    if(this.convertBankCodeSub) this.convertBankCodeSub.unsubscribe();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    this.legalDataFrm.ngSubmit.emit();

    for (const fieldName in this.fControls) {
      if (this.fControls.hasOwnProperty(fieldName)) {
        this.form.get(fieldName).markAsTouched();
        this.form.get(fieldName).updateValueAndValidity();
      }
    }
  }

  onCheckIdentityImg(ev: Event) {
    const inputEl = (ev.target as HTMLInputElement);

    if (inputEl.files && inputEl.files.length > 0) {
      const file = inputEl.files[0];

      this.form.patchValue({ identityImg: file });
      this.form.get('identityImg').markAsTouched();

      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = () => {
        this.form.patchValue({ identityImgURL: reader.result });
        this.form.get('identityImgURL').updateValueAndValidity();
        this.tmpIdentityImg = file.name;
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }

  onCheckPaySlipImg(ev: Event) {
    const inputEl = (ev.target as HTMLInputElement);

    if (inputEl.files && inputEl.files.length > 0) {
      const file = inputEl.files[0];

      this.form.patchValue({ paySlipImg: file });
      this.form.get('paySlipImg').markAsTouched();

      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = () => {
        this.form.patchValue({ paySlipImgURL: reader.result });
        this.form.get('paySlipImgURL').updateValueAndValidity();
        this.tmpPaySlipImg = file.name;
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }

  onCheckTaxImg(ev: Event) {
    const inputEl = (ev.target as HTMLInputElement);

    if (inputEl.files && inputEl.files.length > 0) {
      const file = inputEl.files[0];

      this.form.patchValue({ taxImg: file });
      this.form.get('taxImg').markAsTouched();

      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = () => {
        this.form.patchValue({ taxImgURL: reader.result });
        this.form.get('taxImgURL').updateValueAndValidity();
        this.tmpTaxImg = file.name;
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }

  onClear(input: AbstractControl | null, label: string, ev: Event) {
    switch (label) {
      case 'identityImg':
        this.tmpIdentityImg = '';
        break;

      case 'taxImg':
        this.tmpTaxImg = '';
        break;

      case 'paySlipImg':
        this.tmpPaySlipImg = '';
        break;

      case 'document':
        this.tmpDocument = '';
        break;
    }

    input.reset();
  }

  onKeyDown(bankInfo, noRek) {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.timeLeft = 1;
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.timeLeft > 0) {
        this.timeLeft--;
      } else {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        const noRekTemp = noRek.target.value;
        if (noRekTemp && bankInfo) {
          this.convertBankCodeSub = this._bankService.getBankIdByCode(bankInfo.interbankCode, noRekTemp).subscribe((kcVal) => {  
            this.form.patchValue({ 'bankAccount': kcVal.data.accountName });
          });

          this.kliringCodeSub = this.kliringCode.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe((val) => {
            if (val) {
              this.getBankAccountSub = this._bankService.getBankAccountName(val, noRekTemp).subscribe((res) => {
                if (res.status === 'success') {
                  this.form.patchValue({ 'bankAccount': res.data.bankAccountName });
                  this.form.get('bankAccount').markAsTouched();
                  this.form.get('bankAccount').updateValueAndValidity();
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }
        return;
      }
    }, 500);
  }

  onChangeBank() {
    this.form.patchValue({ 'rekNo': '' });
    this.form.get('rekNo').markAsTouched();
    this.form.get('rekNo').updateValueAndValidity();

    this.form.patchValue({ 'bankAccount': '' });
    this.form.get('bankAccount').markAsTouched();
    this.form.get('bankAccount').updateValueAndValidity();
  };

  get fControls() {
    return this.form.controls;
  }

  private initDropdown() {
    this._bankService.getBank2().then((response) => { 
      this.options = response; 
      this.filteredOptions = this.form.controls.bankName.valueChanges 
      .pipe( 
        startWith<string | User>(''), 
        map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.bankName),
        map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.options.slice()) 
        ); 
    })
  }

  private initForm() {
    let bankName         = null;
    let rekNo            = null;
    let bankAccount      = null;
    const identityImg    = null;
    const taxImg         = null;
    const paySlipImg     = null;
    const identityImgURL = null;
    const taxImgURL      = null;
    const paySlipImgURL  = null;

    const legalData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('legalData'));
    if (legalData) { 
      if (
        _.hasIn(this.profileData, 'borrower.bankAccount.bankName') &&
        !legalData.bankName &&
        _.hasIn(this.profileData, 'borrower.bankAccount.bankCode')
      ) {
        if (this.profileData.borrower.bankAccount.bankCode) {
          bankName = legalData.bankName

        }
      } else {
        // bankName = legalData.bankName;
        bankName = this.form.get('bankName').value;
      }

      if (
        _.hasIn(this.profileData, 'borrower.bankAccount.bankAccountNo') &&
        !legalData.rekNo
      ) {
        rekNo = this.profileData.borrower.bankAccount.bankAccountNo;
      } else {
        rekNo = legalData.rekNo;
      }

      if (
        _.hasIn(this.profileData, 'borrower.bankAccount.bankAccountName') &&
        !legalData.bankAccount
      ) {
        bankAccount = this.profileData.borrower.bankAccount.bankAccountName;
      } else {
        bankAccount = legalData.bankAccount;
      }

      setTimeout(() => {
        for (const fieldName in this.form.controls) {
          if (this.form.controls.hasOwnProperty(fieldName)) {
            if (this.form.get(fieldName).value) {
              this.form.get(fieldName).markAsTouched();
              this.form.get(fieldName).updateValueAndValidity();
            }
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      if (
        _.hasIn(this.profileData, 'borrower.bankAccount.bankName') &&
        _.hasIn(this.profileData, 'borrower.bankAccount.bankCode')
      )
      {
        bankName = this.profileData.borrower.bankAccount.bankName
      }

      if (_.hasIn(this.profileData, 'borrower.bankAccount.bankAccountNo')) {
        rekNo = this.profileData.borrower.bankAccount.bankAccountNo;
      }

      if (_.hasIn(this.profileData, 'borrower.bankAccount.bankAccountName')) {
        bankAccount = this.profileData.borrower.bankAccount.bankAccountName;
      }

      setTimeout(() => {
        for (const fieldName in this.form.controls) {
          if (this.form.controls.hasOwnProperty(fieldName)) {
            if (this.form.get(fieldName).value) {
              this.form.get(fieldName).markAsTouched();
              this.form.get(fieldName).updateValueAndValidity();
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }

    /*const legalData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('legalData'));

     if (legalData) {
     const file = new File([], legalData.tmpIdentityImg.name, {
     type        : legalData.tmpIdentityImg.type,
     lastModified: legalData.tmpIdentityImg.lastModified
     });

     identityImg    = file;
     identityImgURL = legalData.identityImgURL;
     taxImgURL      = legalData.taxImgURL;

     this.tmpIdentityImg = legalData.tmpIdentityImg.name;
     this.tmpTaxImg      = legalData.tmpIdentityImg.name;
     }*/

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      bankName      : [bankName, Validators.required],
      rekNo         : [rekNo, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)]],
      bankAccount   : [bankAccount, Validators.required],
      identityImg   : [identityImg, Validators.required],
      taxImg        : taxImg,
      paySlipImg    : paySlipImg,
      identityImgURL: identityImgURL,
      taxImgURL     : taxImgURL,
      paySlipImgURL : paySlipImgURL,
    });

    this.form.get('bankName').updateValueAndValidity();

    if (_.hasIn(this.profileData, 'borrower.account.identityImage')) {
      if (this.profileData.borrower.account.identityImage) {
        this.form.get('identityImg').clearValidators();
        this.form.get('identityImg').updateValueAndValidity();
      } else {
        this.form.get('identityImg').setValidators([Validators.required]);
        this.form.get('identityImg').updateValueAndValidity();
      }
    }

    this._validationsService.numberFormat(this.form.get('rekNo'));

    this._validationsService.mimeType(this.form.get('identityImg'));
    this._validationsService.sizeLimit(this.form.get('identityImg'), this.limitSizeUpload);

    this._validationsService.mimeType(this.form.get('taxImg'));
    this._validationsService.sizeLimit(this.form.get('taxImg'), this.limitSizeUpload);

    this._validationsService.mimeType(this.form.get('paySlipImg'));
    this._validationsService.sizeLimit(this.form.get('paySlipImg'), this.limitSizeUpload);
   this.limitSizeUpload);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, i was promise that i will update this thread if i find the problem, and here is this my problem.
sorry for late update.
the data type i get in initForm() is string, and the data i send when i select from option is object. so i need to give some conditional..

```
displayFn(user?: User) {
 if ((typeof user) === 'string') {
  return user
 }
 return user ? user.bankName : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `patchValue` or `setValue` to setting the form value from `TS`

**TS**

```
if (_.hasIn(this.profileData, 'borrower.bankAccount.bankName')) {
//By SetValue
this.form.controls['bankName'].setValue(this.profileData.borrower.bankAccount.bankName);
//By PatchValue
this.form.controls['bankName'].patchValue(this.profileData.borrower.bankAccount.bankName);}
```

I just review your whole code you are setting the value before initializing the form

```
first initialize the form

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
   bankName : [bankName, Validators.required], 
   rekNo : [rekNo, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)]], 
   bankAccount : [bankAccount, Validators.required],
   identityImg : [identityImg, Validators.required],
   taxImg : taxImg, paySlipImg : paySlipImg, 
   identityImgURL: identityImgURL, 
   taxImgURL : taxImgURL, 
   paySlipImgURL : paySlipImgURL
 });

// then set the value 
this.form.controls['bankName'].setValue(this.profileData.borrower.bankAccount.bankName);
```

Comment: `setValue` and `patchValue` is only work after initialization of your form. So you need to write `setValue` and `patchValue` after the form initialization is completed. can you provide the whole code of your ts so we will get better idea what want wrong.

Comment: i updated my question sir, please kindly help me. i get stuck here. :)

Comment: You can try like this `this.form.controls['bankName'].setValue(this.profileData.borrower.bankAccount.bankName);` let me know if it is working or not

Comment: its always return undifined error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined. i have no idea what i miss here..

Comment: its not working i dunno why,, anyway when i try to console.log, the value is showing. even when i try to hard code the value, its still not showing. but thank you for helping me dude, i have no idea why, and ill try to update this thread when i solved this issue